# Continuous function and average

Tags: calculus

if  $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $x_1,\ldots ,x_n \in [a,b]$ are arbitrary, then there exist some $c\in [a,b]$ such that $$f(c)=\dfrac{1}{n}[f(x_1)+\cdots + f(x_n)].$$ I know that I should use intermediate value theorem, but what   should I do first?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_{min}$ be such $f(x_{min}) = \min{f(x_i)}$ and $x_{max}$ be such $f(x_{max}) = max{f(x_i)}$   $x_{max}, x_{min}$ to }  Then $f(x_{min}) \le \frac 1 n [f(x_1) +.... + f(x_n)] \le f(x_{max})$ so by intermediate value theorem there is a $c \in [\min(x_{min},x_{max}), \max(x_{min}, x_{max})] \subset [a,b]$ such that $f(c) =\frac 1 n [f(x_1) +.... + f(x_n)]$.

Comment: I swear I didn't see user284105 post be for I posted!  Same language down the the choice of variable!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_{min} = \min_{1 \leq i \leq n} f(x_i)$ and $x_{max} = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} f(x_i)$. Then
$$f(x_{min}) \leq \dfrac{1}{n}[f(x_1)+\cdots + f(x_n)] \leq f(x_{max})$$
So by the intermediate value theorem there is a $c$ between $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$ with $f(c)= \dfrac{1}{n}[f(x_1)+\cdots + f(x_n)]$.

Comment: minor minor minor nitpick:  if x_min = min f(x_i) wouldn't that mean x_min is one of the f(x_i) and not one of the x_i?